# Responsive Layout

Tags: gridview, responsive-design

I've currently creating partially-responsive layout template (for tablets and desktop). I'm having issues on width in pixels and percentage.

I have 2 main columns - let's call these columns LEFT and RIGHT.

I've put fixed width for the LEFT column, because I need a fixed width for this (of about 500px).

I want the RIGHT column to "float left" and use as much space as it can use from its outer container. I want the RIGHT block to be responisve according the screen size changes.

Both columns are floating left.

This works well if my LEFT column floats left, and has a width: 500px, and the RIGHT column floats left, but has no width. The content of RIGHT simply stretches as far as it can, floating next to LEFT.

When I resize my browser to a smaller width, the content within the RIGHT block (e.g. a long line of text) is supposed to actually float  left, and let any text wrap onto two or more lines. However, the text does not wrap, instead the whole RIGHT column naturally falls to the bottom beneath the LEFT column, because its content is too wide for this smaller screen size. This is natural, and I think we all know this problem. On a fixed width layout, you would always give a WIDTH to the RIGHT column as well. However, now I am trying to get away without specifying a width, but this doesn't seem to be correct since the column falls to the bottom.

eg:
 
  some text
 
 
  some text

Please help/advise me to solve the above problem. Does any solution exist for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` to force them to perform the way you want, then remove those styles when sizing down for mobile. Here's a jsfiddle I made for someone with a similar problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/hp8Vg/1/

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this http://jsfiddle.net/TZrw7/. Set the overflow on the #right element to hidden, that'll do it.

```
#left
{
     width: 500px;
     float: left;
     border: 2px solid #f0f
}

#right
{
     overflow:hidden;
     border: 2px solid #00f
}
```